# mysql select those items where prices are not same

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

I have orders and order_details tables

want to select all those items which are sold in more than one price
eg. item_id#1 sold in $5 10 time and in $6 3 time and in $7 1 time

my table fields are

```
SELECT `id`,`order_id`,`item_id`,`price`,`qty`,`subtotal`  FROM `order_details`
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `GROUP BY` with `HAVING` Clause in which whether exists more than one price value whenever counted distinctly  :

```
SELECT `item_id`  
  FROM `order_details`
 GROUP BY `item_id`
HAVING COUNT( DISTINCT `price`) > 1
```